# regex not working in bs4

Tags: python, regex, urllib2, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract some links from a specific filehoster on watchseriesfree.to website. In the following case I want rapidvideo links, so I use regex to filter out those  tags with text containing rapidvideo

```
import re
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def gethtml(link):
    req = urllib2.Request(link, headers={'User-Agent': "Magic Browser"})
    con = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    html = con.read()
    return html


def findLatest():
    url = "https://watchseriesfree.to/serie/Madam-Secretary"
    head = "https://watchseriesfree.to"

    soup = BeautifulSoup(gethtml(url), 'html.parser')
    latep = soup.find("a", title=re.compile('Latest Episode'))

    soup = BeautifulSoup(gethtml(head + latep['href']), 'html.parser')
    firstVod = soup.findAll("tr",text=re.compile('rapidvideo'))

    return firstVod

print(findLatest())
```

However, the above code returns a blank list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: NB: `findAll` seems to have been renamed to `find_all` in bs4. (Apparently, the bs3 version has been kept around, but I'd update your code anyway.) The `find_all` function signature also does not have a `text` parameter, but rather a `string` parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
firstVod = soup.findAll("tr",text=re.compile('rapidvideo'))
```

When `BeautifulSoup` will apply your text regex pattern, it would use [`.string` attribute](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) values of all the matched `tr` elements. Now, the `.string` has this important caveat - **when an element has multiple children, `.string` is `None`**:

> If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what `.string` should refer to, so `.string` is defined to be `None`.

Hence, you have no results.

What you can do is to check the actual text of the `tr` elements by using a [searching function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) and calling `.get_text()`:

```
soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'tr' and 'rapidvideo' in tag.get_text())
```