# Beautifulsoup doesn't match text when there is <br/>

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

```
x = '<td class="greymeta">Posted Date:<br/> </td>'

parse = BeautifulSoup(x,"lxml")

parse.find("td",text=re.compile(r"^Posted Date:")) # doesn't return anything
```

if there is no `<br/>` within `<td>` tag:

```
x = '<td class="greymeta">Posted Date: </td>' 
parse.find("td",text=re.compile(r"^Posted Date:")) # returns output correcly
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regex not working in bs4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036243/regex-not-working-in-bs4)

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43036333/7832176) by @alecxe answers your question perfectly. `soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == 'td' and 'Posted Date:' in tag.get_text())`